# Wrapping around php filters function

Tags: php, filter

I'm trying to make a function to wrap around php filters:

Something like this:

```
function validate($data, $args, $errorMsg)
{

}
```

So you can validate data like this:

```
$data = array(
    'product_id'    => 'libgd<script>',
    'component'     => '10',
    'versions'      => '2.0.33',
    'testscalar'    => array('2', '23', '10', '12'),
    'testarray'     => '2',
);

$args = array(
    'product_id'   => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'component'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY, 
                            'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 10)
                           ),
    'versions'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    'doesnotexist' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'testscalar'   => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                           ),
    'testarray'    => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'flags'  => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
                           )

);
```

However I also want to display error messages if one of the filters returns false, so for example if components returns false (e.g. not an integer or out of range), I want to create an error message such as "[field] is not an integer". How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You Could try throwing an Exceptions

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

is if there is an error in validate(), error using this

```
throw new Exception('[field] is not an integer');
```

so validate would be

```
try(
   Validate();
)
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think that the right exception to throw during validation is `InvalidArgumentException`.